# Make the image layout more organized using bootstrap and CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

So I have basically used manual percentages to make these images lie next together. As you see they are not very neatly layout or organized. How can I make it look more dashing?

Here's the code:

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" style=" margin-top: 90px; ">


    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <img src="./assets/img/glass.jpg" class="img-responsive " style="width:95%"/>
                <img src="./assets/img/rift.jpg" class="img-responsive m-y-1" style="width:95%;"/>

            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <img src="./assets/img/mhacks.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%; "/>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <img src="./assets/img/mindwave.png" class="img-responsive" style="width:120%;"/>
                <img src="./assets/img/VR.png" class="img-responsive m-y-1" style="width:120%;"/>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



</div>
```

Here's how it looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6f3B.jpg

Also here's the link to the website: 
monajalal.github.io

Any suggestion is really appreciated. I wonder if there's a more straightforward method to image layout or any automatic method?

Comment: You need to generate thumbnails with exact width and height elsewhere you can not achieve an organized layout regardless of aspect ratio.

Comment: As a simple method you may replace images with DIVs with exact width and height and `overflow:hidden` and put images inside them so the images are visually cropped.

Comment: Try this website for easy image resizing: http://images.weserv.nl. Use it too make all images the same size.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour I'm a beginner so if you can provide a jsfiddle that would be more helpful!

Comment: @JoostS is there something we could do from CSS side? or bootstrap side?

Answer (score 0):

Set each image as a background image in a div:

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" style=" margin-top: 90px; ">
     <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <div style="background: url('./assets/img/glass.jpg'); background-size: cover;" class="img-responsive"></div>
                <div style="background: url('./assets/img/rift.jpg'); background-size: cover;" class="img-responsive"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <div style="background: url('./assets/img/mhacks.jpg'); background-size: cover;" class="img-responsive-large"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <div style="background: url('./assets/img/mindwave.png'); background-size: cover;" class="img-responsive"></div>
                <div style="background: url('./assets/img/VR.png'); background-size: cover;" class="img-responsive"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then set this css:

```
.img-responsive {padding-top: 60%; margin-bottom: 10px;}
.img-responsive-large {height: 208px; margin-bottom: 10px;}

@media screen and (max-width: 940px) {
  .img-responsive-large {height: auto; padding-top: 60%;}
}
```

Comment: your answer doesn't work! Have you tried it? Can you show it in jsfiddle that is working?

Comment: This is what I got after adding stuff to style.css and then having that in index.html http://imgur.com/mRoWpwv

Answer (score 0):

Try this... What I did was work with the grid. Use the padding from columns and even it with margins between the images, also set the images to 100% width. Class img-responsive sets a max-width of 100%, at least this way the image will fill the column.

```
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <img src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png" class="img-responsive"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <img src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png" class="img-responsive "/>
                    <img src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png" class="img-responsive m-y-1"/>

                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <img src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png" class="img-responsive"/>
                    <img src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png" class="img-responsive m-y-1"/>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Remove the inline styling - and instead target the images in the css and add this.

```
.jumbotron img { width: 100%; margin: 15px 0; }
```

Comment: your code doesn't work! This is how it will show http://imgur.com/mtFaxyD

Comment: Not sure exactly what your trying to do or the effect your trying to get, but instead of a coding fix, why don't you try opening your photos in photoshop and cropping them so they align equally. Portrait and landscape images will never align correctly otherwise.